# Whats wrong with this scala worksheet

Tags: scala

```
package calculator


object test {
import Polynomial._

  val a = calculator.Var(4.0);
  val b = calculator.Var(4.0);
  val c = calculator.Var(1.0);

  val delta = computeDelta(a,b,c);

  delta();

  val solution = computeSolutions(a,b,c,delta);

  solution();
}
```

I am trying to figure out why the polynomial assignment in the Coursera course is not yeilding the right solutions. I wrote this small scala worksheet , but I get an "illegal start of simple expression" in the scala worksheet. It happens at `val delta` and `val solution`.

Comment: Make sure Var is returning values. If possible post complete code

Comment: Which IDE are you working with?

Comment: This is official scala IDE. Funnily , i tried the same above code by adding a Main in Polynomial.java and it worked. Since it wasn't a scala worksheet , I did a `println` for `delta()` and `solution()` and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is delta is a variable which holds the output of computeDelta method.

And you are using delta as a method call, `delta()`

For example,

```
scala> def greet() = "Hello World!"
greet: ()String

scala> val greeting = greet
greeting: String = Hello World!

scala> greeting()
<console>:10: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps.
Unspecified value parameter index.
              greeting()
                      ^

scala> greeting
res14: String = Hello World!
```

When i called greeting variable with paranthersis, notice the error, scala treats it as a function call but greeting is a variable. So when i use it again without parenthesis. It works. You can do so if you have stored a partiall applied function to your variable. Since it is a function, you will get error.

Comment: Delta is of type Signal , that has update and apply defined on it. So the parenthesis are good, like i updated in the above comments the same code works inside main() method in scala app. Looks like some bug in worksheet.

Comment: There might be bug. Strange it worked with parenthesis because it didn't work in repl.